# PHP My SQL Error Strict standards: Resource ID#11 used as offset, casting to integer (11)

Tags: php, mysql

my Code

```
function db_fetch_array($query_id = '')
    {
        if(!$query_id)
        {
            $query_id = $this->query_result;
        }

        if($query_id)
        {
            // success
            $this->row[$query_id] = mysql_fetch_array($query_id);
            return $this->row[$query_id];
        }
        else
        {
            // failure
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `query_result` usually is resource with number, using it as key for an array is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

for starters i would do something like this:

```
if (empty($query_id))
```

instead of

```
if (!$query_id)
```

since !$query_id does not check for empty strings

Further, the error seems to be an issue with using the $query_id as an array key. You may need to find a different identifier

as per divaka's potential alternative in comments below:

Use something else for a key. You can fetch the result first, then get the id of the row and apply it as a key in you array

Comment: or even better, use `$query_id = null` in the arguments

Comment: Hello Dear actually I am facing issue in this line. That was not working  $this->row[$query_id] = mysql_fetch_array($query_id);

Comment: see second part of my answer - $query_id (connection resource) is not a valid array key. You can try to parse the numbers out of the resource identifier but you would be better off using something else to identify the result set

Comment: $query_id is a resource and you are trying to use it as an integer, this is the error

Comment: what is the solution dear?

Comment: Use something else for a key. You can fetch the result first, then get the id of the row and apply it as a key in you array.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to stack several database connections,
consider linking the database in the constructor and instanciate several of these classes, which you can hold in an array.

Example:

```
class Database
{
    protected $link;
    public function __construct($user, $pass, $host) {
        $this->link = new Mysqli(/* ... */);
    }
    public function fetch($query) {
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($query);
        /* ... */
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Now have your databases in an array:

```
$db[0]  = new Database('root', 'root', 'server1');
$db[1]  = new Database('root', 'root', 'server2');
$db['bigCluster'] = new Database('user01', 'passwd', 'cluster.your.biz');

$result = $db[0]->fetch("SELECT * FROM table");
```

This way you have way better access, control and debugging is easier.

To say something about your code:

```
function db_fetch_array($query_id = '') { /* .... */ }
```

This function accepts an empty parameter, thus, allowing the user to fetch from a non-existent database connection. Which results in an error. Don't allow it!
Even better, typehint it:

```
public function db_fetch_array(\Mysqli $query_id) { /* .... */ }
```

Solves all your problems at once!

If you need an it your way tho, try the following, giving you a unique, printable id to use as an array key:

```
$query_id = md5((string)$query_id);
```

Have a look at the Zend code style guide and modern PHP design patterns, this will help you to increase your code quality by a few hundred percent.